# Access injectable value to SubModule when importing it in App Module

Tags: angular

Okay, so, here's some context...

I've got a feature module that requires a string value to be passed to its `forRoot` static method when imported in `app.module.ts`, like this:

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ /* ... */ ],
    imports: [
        MyModule.forRoot('the configuration string') // <- here
    ],
    providers: [/* ... */],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But I don't want to pass a hardcoded string. Instead I want to retrieve its value from a configuration object fetched from my backend server before app initialization, then declared as an `extraProvider` when calling `platformBrowserDynamic`, like this:

```js
// main.ts
Env.getConfig$().subscribe(config => {
    platformBrowserDynamic([
      { provide: AppConfig, useValue: config } // <- here
    ]).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
});
```

I know that the config can be injected in a service with this configuration (I tested it):

```js
export class AnyService {

  constructor(
    private config: AppConfig
  ) {
    console.log(config); // <- Displays the expected config object
  }
}
```

My issue is that I want to access this injected configuration object when importing `MyModule`in the `AppModule`. Something like:

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ /* ... */ ],
    imports: [
        MyModule.forRoot(config.stringParamValue) // <- How to inject the AppConfig instance?
    ],
    providers: [/* ... */],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I thought about something involving a `forRoot` static method in `AppModule`, that would inject the `AppConfig` token using an `@Inject` decorator... but it's seems a little hacky somehow...

I'd also like to avoid storing my config in some kind of global variable in the subscribe callback of the `Env.getConfig$` observable.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try define an injection token inside the module (MyModule in this case). And try using like this :

```
    // main.ts
Env.getConfig$().subscribe(config => {
    platformBrowserDynamic([
      { provide: YourToken, useValue: config } // <- here
    ]).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
});
```

[api doc](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken)
[sample implementation](https://medium.com/@michelestieven/angular-writing-configurable-modules-69e6ea23ea42)

Comment: OMG! So simple!
Of course I could do that. In fact, I already did defined an injection token in `MyModule` ; it was provided by the `forRoot` method with the value passed as an argument. Very little to do to implement your advice.
Thanks a bunch!