# Read api url from local json file in app.module

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm working on an Angular project. This project will be established in different addresses. And each api link will be different. Instead of changing and building the apiUrl provider in app.module for each, I would like to use it locally by keeping these addresses in a json file.

My current code in app.module.ts;

```
providers: [
   { provide: 'apiUrl', useValue: 'http://api.xxxx' },
   { provide: 'imgUrl', useValue: 'http://img.xxxx' },
   ...
]
```

Since these addresses will be different in each project, I will keep these addresses in a local json file as follows;

assets/data/links.json;

```
{
  "apiUrl": "http://api.xxxx",
  "imgUrl": "http://img.xxxx",
}
```

I tried to do this using APP_INITIALIZER, but didn't succeed. Because after reading the values in this json file, I could not pass this to apiUrl and imgUrl providers in app.module.ts.

Is there a solution to this? Or how can I use these links through a local file?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802498/access-injectable-value-to-submodule-when-importing-it-in-app-module/58802995#58802995)

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of environment file which is located in environments folder for this purpose.

Assume you need to build the projects with different api urls for dev and prod, in that case , you can create a environment file like below.

```
---environment.prod.ts---
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'https://api.prod.com',
  imgUrl: 'https://img.prod.com'
};

---environment.dev.ts---
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'https://api.dev.com',
  imgUrl: 'https://img.dev.com'
};
```

Note:: for local , by default properties will be read by **environment.ts**

Once you created the above files , you can define them in angular.json for building like below.

add the records under configurations as follows...

```
"configurations": {
        "dev": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
            }
          ]
        },
        "prod": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
```

and for serve purpose, you can add config under serve as follows,

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "movenow:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "movenow:build:dev"
            },
            "prod": {
              "browserTarget": "movenow:build:prod"
            }
          }
        }
```

you can access the environment variables as follows.

```
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

export component Component1 {

       apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
       imgUrl = environment.imgUrl;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try the method you call but my goal here is not to change the test environment and the api link in live environment.

I want to change the api link of a built project from a local file. So I don't have to build it after I change the api link.