# Access methods of ionic app in Electron renderer window

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, electron

I am porting a web-app written with the ionic/angular framework to a desktop app using Electron. I would like to keep the web-app code unchanged as drop-in code to simplify maintenance. I have it working well, and I am putting in the finishing touches.

The final touch is to save the user’s preferences (such as choice of kg vs lbs) between uses of the desktop app. The web app allows changing the preferences with buttons but does not have persistence.

I have figured how to navigate the DOM during a window closes event to determine what the user has chosen, so that I can read the current state and store it.

What I have not been able to do is set the preferences when the page loads at app start. My plan is to add code in `preload.js` in the `window.eventEventListener` `DOMContentLoaded` event handler. I have tried the following, each of which works on a modified version of the example code for electron, which does not ionic or angular, but not on the target code itself.

Calling the instance method `HomePage.toggleKG()`, or `toggleKG()`. Both get a not defined error
Finding the user button in the DOM and then using its .`click()` event. I can find the button, but calling the click event does not throw an error, but nothing changes.

It seems that either angular or ionic is creating a context or closure which prevents me from accessing the methods or even the button.

How can I access one or the other?

Comment: You can implement it in your application code (`HomePage`) using localstorage or using ionic storage [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage). Even if you manage to do it i don't think it's a feasible solution.

Comment: I do not want to change the web app code, because this application shares code with the true web app and the mobile version. I want the web-app code to be unchanged, and all the other features to be in the desktop electron implementation. This will make maintenance easier.

Comment: You can create an Angular service which handles storage operations which has dummy implementation by default and in your Electron application override it with a service which has a real implementation. And why web and mobile users don't need that feature.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how this would solve the problem. I already have services in the ionic/angular web app. When I build this, it creates a huge main.js which rolls that all together. I do not want to have a separate ionic/angular build just for the desktop version. It seems that creating another service, with a dummy version and another working one for desktop would require separate builds of the ionic/angular web app. If I could just simulate a user click I could avoid all of that.

Comment: You won't have different builds. Only difference will be the how you bootstrap your angular app. Already web, mobile and desktop have different initialization. All you need to do is in your `Electron` version of bootstrapping provide a `StorageService` and override the original dummy service. You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802498/access-injectable-value-to-submodule-when-importing-it-in-app-module/58802995#58802995) example for providing service or token while bootstrapping angular.

Comment: My apologize if I am being dense. I am a relative newbie with `Angular`and `Ionic`. As I mentioned, I have services in my web app which are in separate `.ts` files, but when I build the web app, all of them get rolled into one huge `main.js` file. This is what is used in the `Electron` app. Your example has a service in a `.ts` file. I do not see how to roll that into my app without a separate build, with the dummy, and with a non-dummy version. It seems that the bootstrapping occurs automagically when `main.js` is loaded. What am I missing? I checked and I used `Angular 2.4.8`.

Comment: You will have one single build that has dummy service implemented. But instead in your electron app where yo bootstrap the angular app, you will provide a service that replaces the dummy service. The rest of application remains same.

Comment: The index.html file only loads two scripts, `polyfills.js` and `main.js` neither are the original Typscript files, so I still do not understand how to add a service to the startup process, which is what I assume you mean by bootstrap.